# How to make enableEdgeToEdge work in Navigation Drawer Views Activity example?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use the exact example from **Navigation Drawer Views Activity**

[image]

When I run, it looks as the following

[image]

Based on https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge#kotlin

I add single line of `enableEdgeToEdge()` to

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

Now, it looks as the following.

[image]

I thought the `AppBarLayout` is now behind the status bar. I add a solid color to `AppBarLayout` as following

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">
```

But, the outcome still look the same.

May I know, what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` sets statusbar color by default to `android.R.color.colorPrimaryDark` when `fitsSystemWindows` is set to `true`. You can override it programatically by `DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor()` method. Or you may set value to above attr in your app's theme like:

```
 <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">?colorPrimary</item>
```

You may also set `fitsSystemWindows` to `false` but this probably require you to install your own insets like:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.app_bar_main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(0, systemBars.top/*for statusbar*/, 0, 0)
            insets
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Using android:colorPrimaryDark works for me. May I know, how does `enableEdgeToEdge` related to `fitsSystemWindows(true)`, as mentioned in your answer?

Comment: My understanding is `enableEdgeToEdge` sets `fitsSystemWindows()` to false but `DrawerLayout`  enforces it back to true when `android:fitsSystemWindows=true` is set on it.