# How to make enableEdgeToEdge workable for app with DrawerLayout + BottomAppBar + BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin

For an app with `DrawerLayout` + `BottomAppBar` + `BottomNavigationView`, I try to implement edge-to-edge display.

For top status bar, I was able to make it work by using

1. `enableEdgeToEdge()`

To ensure the status bar having correct color, I use the following

```
fun updateStatusBarColor(@ColorInt statusBarColor: Int) {
    drawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(statusBarColor)
}
```

based on the answer from [How to make enableEdgeToEdge work in Navigation Drawer Views Activity example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78008746/how-to-make-enableedgetoedge-work-in-navigation-drawer-views-activity-example)

However, it still have undesired white region for bottom bar area.

[image]

If I try to solve this issue, by changing the bottom navigation bar color

```
window.navigationBarColor = Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
```

It seems "solve" the issue. But, when the `DrawerLayout` is sliding out, the solid red color will block the `DrawerLayout`.

[image]

May I know, what is the correct way to implement edge-to-edge display, for app with DrawerLayout + BottomAppBar + BottomNavigationView?

I provide the complete source code as follow :-

https://github.com/yccheok/stackoverflow/tree/master/enableEdgeToEdge/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in the DrawerLayout (in layout xml) so it won't reinstall back the top and bottom insets. But this will cause the appbar to move/overlap towards the status bar (as expected behavior). You can address that by adding your own inset(top margin) to the appbar in your activity's onCreate():

```
 ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.toolbar)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.updateLayoutParams<AppBarLayout.LayoutParams> {
                topMargin = systemBars.top
            }
            insets
        }
```

This way (i.e with `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`), you don't anymore need to set the statusbar color.

Tip: You can set `app:topInsetScrimEnabled="false"` on your `NavigationView` to remove the top scrim/shadow of the drawer panel.

Comment: Does that also mean, we should avoid using `enableEdgeToEdge()`, and use `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`?

Comment: I suggest to use `enabledEdgeEdge()` for better backward compatibility. Basically it does the same `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` but also sets system bars transparent.